# Pipe file list to vim and browser them like a folder

Tags: netrw, file, open

Is it possible to pipe list of files e.g. from grep and have this file list opened in vim file manager in similar fashion like when you open a folder with vim?

Note that I do not want to just write the file names into vim buffer like a text. I want vim to treat them as if these files were in a folder and I would be able to choose which one to open.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to your great advice I could add these two functions in my .bashrc, they do almost exactly what I want:

```bash
# Find files by name in the notes and open them as subset in vim, opens first file in the search in the buffer:
function notefv {
    vim --cmd 'set efm=%f' -c copen -q <(find ~/Notes -name "*$1*")
}

# Grep notes for a keyword, open the result in vim quickfix list, opens first file in the search in the buffer
function noteg {
    vim --cmd 'set efm=%f' -c copen -q <(grep -irl --color $1 ~/Notes/*)
}
```

This uses native vim functionality. if I'll have nothing to do, I'll try to rewrite it so that the subset of files is opened in dervish or NerdTree.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: The file manager (netrw) is not really suitable to display a subset of files, or files in separate directories... The quickfix list is typically the place to do that. If you have a list of filenames, one quick-and-dirty approach is to use something like `vim --cmd 'set efm=%f' -c copen -q <(find . -type f)`. See `:help -q` in Vim to see how to populate the quickfix list when invoking Vim. With `grep` it might be even easier, since Vim might be expecting that kind of format for the quickfix list..

Comment: In addition to @filbranden s comment: if you wanted to pipe it into the arguments list in vim, look at `xargs`, e.g. `ls | xargs vim -o --  # open all files in split`. I would suggest to add th `--`, because otherwise you might run into issues if you had files starting with a `-` ;)

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, are you already aware of the [`gf`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#gf) command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three options depending on what you are trying to achieve:

1. If you specifically want the output of grep, then you can just use [`:grep`/`:vimgrep`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#grep) from within vim.  This will populate the quickfix window with a list of files which you can browse and press Enter to open.
2. If you have a different command that generates your list of files, but it is relatively static (or perhaps just takes a single argument) then the native way to do this is to write your own function making use of [`setqflist()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setqflist%28%29) to populate the quickfix window.  I use this in my own configuration as shown [here](https://github.com/andrewlkho/dotfiles/blob/0601cba7cd0d6d2fcbcd3d8f8b850c67c811e8af/vim/.local/etc/vim/autoload/local.vim#L21-L35).
3. Finally, if the command to generate the files changes a lot, then as Matt [notes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28391/32132), a plugin like [vim-dirvish](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish) can achieve this.  Using this plugin, any buffer with `filetype=dirvish` will be treated as a list of paths to then manipulate (including open).  This essentally provides some niceities around [`gf`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#gf).  You can then make use of [`:redir`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Aredir) and [`system()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#system%28%29).

I have assumed that you meant to open in vim itself and not [vifm](https://vifm.info/) when you said "vim file manager".

Answer (score 2):

Unlike netrw, there are Vim file managers who follow a different paradigm: simply fill in some lines and present'em "as if it's a file list".

The most well-known "buffer-like file manager" is probably [vim-dirvish](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish). As a shameless plug, I also wrote one of my own called [vim-drvo](https://github.com/matveyt/vim-drvo).

So you can create a buffer containing random file names, type `:setf drvo` and `:setl bufhidden=hide` (to keep contents if buffer becomes hidden) and it just works out-of-the-box.